# Can't launch Oracle Mapviewer through Browser: JSP error

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, oracle11g, oracle-map-viewer

I have followed all the installation steps for Oracle Mapviewer, I am currently trying to install the "mapviewer11p5_quickstart", everything goes well until I try accessing mapViewer through the browser through "http://localhost:8888/mapviewer" it redirects me to a "http://localhost:8888/mapviewer/faces/home.jspx" and I get a

```
500 Internal Server Error

OracleJSP: An error occurred. Consult your application/system administrator for support. Programmers should consider setting the init-param debug_mode to "true" to see the complete exception message.
```

This is the output on my command line:

```
C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart>start.bat

C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart>C:

C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart>cd "C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home"

C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" -server -Xmx768M -jar oc4j.jar
Apr 30, 2017 9:32:47 PM com.evermind.server.XMLDataSourcesConfig parseRootNode
INFO: Legacy datasource detected...attempting to convert to new syntax.
2017-04-30 21:32:48.301 NOTIFICATION JMSServer[]: OC4J JMS server recovering transactions (commit 0) (rollback 0) (prepared 0).
2017-04-30 21:32:48.332 NOTIFICATION JMSServer[]: OC4J JMS server recovering local transactions Queue[jms/Oc4jJmsExceptionQueue].
17/04/30 21:32:50 WARNING: Code-source C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib\activation.jar (from WEB-INF/lib/ directory in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib) has the same filename but is not identical to /C:/Program Installs/mv11ps5_quickstart/mapviewer11p5_quickstart/oc4j/j2ee/home/lib/activation.jar (from <code-source> (ignore manifest Class-Path) in META-INF/boot.xml in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader mapviewer.web.web:0.0.0.
17/04/30 21:32:50 WARNING: Code-source C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib\dms.jar (from WEB-INF/lib/ directory in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib) has the same filename but is not identical to /C:/Program Installs/mv11ps5_quickstart/mapviewer11p5_quickstart/oc4j/lib/dms.jar (from <code-source> (ignore manifest Class-Path) in META-INF/boot.xml in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader mapviewer.web.web:0.0.0.
17/04/30 21:32:50 WARNING: Code-source C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib\ojdl.jar (from WEB-INF/lib/ directory in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib) has the same filename but is not identical to /C:/Program Installs/mv11ps5_quickstart/mapviewer11p5_quickstart/oc4j/diagnostics/lib/ojdl.jar (from <code-source> (ignore manifest Class-Path) in META-INF/boot.xml in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader mapviewer.web.web:0.0.0.
17/04/30 21:32:50 WARNING: Code-source C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib\runtime12.jar (from WEB-INF/lib/ directory in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib) has the same filename but is not identical to /C:/Program Installs/mv11ps5_quickstart/mapviewer11p5_quickstart/oc4j/sqlj/lib/runtime12.jar (from <code-source> (ignore manifest Class-Path) in META-INF/boot.xml in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader mapviewer.web.web:0.0.0.
17/04/30 21:32:50 WARNING: Code-source C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib\xmlparserv2.jar (from WEB-INF/lib/ directory in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\lib) has the same filename but is not identical to /C:/Program Installs/mv11ps5_quickstart/mapviewer11p5_quickstart/oc4j/lib/xmlparserv2.jar (from <code-source> (ignore manifest Class-Path) in META-INF/boot.xml in C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\oc4j.jar). If it contains different versions of the same classes, it will be masked as the latter is already visible in the search path of loader mapviewer.web.web:0.0.0.
2017-04-30 21:32:51.176 NOTIFICATION oms root path:  C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\
2017-04-30 21:32:51.176 NOTIFICATION mbean domain: mapviewer
2017-04-30 21:32:51.191 NOTIFICATION OMSConfig mbean registered.
2017-04-30 21:32:51.191 NOTIFICATION MapTileServer root path:  C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\
2017-04-30 21:32:51.207 NOTIFICATION mbean domain: mapviewer
2017-04-30 21:32:51.207 NOTIFICATION MapViewer server version: Ver11_1_1_6_B120220
2017-04-30 21:32:51.207 NOTIFICATION MCSConfig mbean registered.
2017-04-30 21:32:51.207 NOTIFICATION using default config file: C:\Program Installs\mv11ps5_quickstart\mapviewer11p5_quickstart\oc4j\j2ee\home\applications\mapviewer\web\WEB-INF\conf\mapViewerConfig.xml
2017-04-30 21:32:51.223 WARNING destroying ALL mapmaker instances.
17/04/30 21:32:51 Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0)  initialized
2017-04-30 21:32:51.269 NOTIFICATION Using system default dpi: 192
2017-04-30 21:32:51.269 NOTIFICATION Setting default dpi to: 96
2017-04-30 21:32:51.301 NOTIFICATION Spatial Provider shapefileSDP has been registered.
2017-04-30 21:32:51.301 NOTIFICATION Map Recycling thread started.
2017-04-30 21:32:51.301 NOTIFICATION *** Oracle MapViewer started. ***
2017-04-30 21:32:52.254 NOTIFICATION *** Oracle Feature of Interest (FOI) Server started. ***
2017-04-30 21:32:52.285 NOTIFICATION *** Oracle MapTileServer started. ***
2017-04-30 21:32:54.912 NOTIFICATION  J2EE JSP-0008 Unable to dispatch JSP Page : Exception:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/CharacterEncoding
```

help me get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found that sun.io classes are deprecated from jdk 8, I installed jdk 7 and got it to work!